# WCF Post using SoapUI 404 not found

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-404, soapui

I have wcf service hosted on IIS. https://sample.azurewebsites.net/service1.svc. When i tried to access it from browser, i can access it and also able to see the WSDL.

I tried to test one of the methods inside it using SoapUI. I am able to create new Soap project. I have could see the all methods inside it in SoapUI. When i hit send in Soap UI i am seeing 404 not found.

Request :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:getSomeData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:inputCode>?</tem:inputCode>
      </tem:getSomeData>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Resposne:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie: locale=en-GB; path=/
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=f7e6867f2c1126df6e85985ad62253202300d1c2e74ff407dbd0aca8c239ebb9;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=sample.azurewebsites.net
Date: Thu, 03 Jan 2019 05:37:26 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Log:

```
Thu Jan 03 11:10:51 IST 2019:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Thu Jan 03 11:10:51 IST 2019:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /service1.svc HTTP/1.1
Thu Jan 03 11:10:51 IST 2019:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Thu Jan 03 11:10:51 IST 2019:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Thu Jan 03 11:10:51 IST 2019:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Thu Jan 03 11:10:51 IST 2019:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /service1.svc HTTP/1.1
Thu Jan 03 11:10:52 IST 2019:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Thu Jan 03 11:10:52 IST 2019:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Thu Jan 03 11:10:52 IST 2019:INFO:Got response for [WSHttpBinding_IService1.getSomeData:Request 2] in 1124ms (0 bytes)
```

Comment: When we use the soapui send the request. The SOAPAction field specify the method we want to call. And endpoint address field shows where the service address. What are the value of these fields? How do you design and publish your service (now is unavailable)?

Comment: In WS-A i mentioned it.

Action : http://tempuri.org/IService1/getSomeData

Comment: Additinally, it works fine in my localhost!

Comment: which binding does your server use to create the wcf service?